# Live Feed of Questions

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, feed

Hi all,

I was wondering, is there a way to have my browser update (live) when a new question appears in the Stack Overflow feed? I've heard of RSS--does that have anything to do with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've heard of RSS--does that have anything to do with this?

If you have a feed aggregation application available (e.g. Internet Explorer or Mozilla Thunderbird) you can subscribe to RSS feeds. Depending on your browser there should be a highlight icon that picks up the RSS links within each Stack Exchange site page.

Using the multi-site tag following capability of http://StackExchange.com you can create your own mix of tags and sites to follow.

Comment: Huh... I *do* see the RSS icon in Firefox, right beside the Bookmark icon in the address bar. I clicked that and subscribed... but what happens next? How do I view the constantly-updating feed? (Did I go through the right steps?)

Comment: @Lambert depends what you subscribed with. I think the default would be "Live Bookmarks" which is internal to FF (and I've never used).

Comment: Yes, I actually subscribed with Live Bookmarks, and I didn't see anything live about it... I had to explicitly refresh it, which was confusing. Do I really have to use Thunderbird or something else for this? It seems like Firefox should have this feature...

Comment: @Lambert Why not ask about effective use of FF Live Bookmarks on http://superuser.com ? (I use an, apparently now, abandon-ware aggregator that allows 30min or even 15min refresh cycles.)

Comment: That sounds like a great idea. +1 Thank you for your help! :)